# FragmentTransaction 'add' not working

Tags: android

I am having problems adding a fragment to a frame layout placeholder:

```
    TestDialogFragment newFragment = new TestDialogFragment();
    int id = R.id.fragment_placeholder; //id of the FrameLayout placeholder for the TestDialogFragment
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(id, newFragment, "testdialogfragment").commit();
```

I have breakpoints in the onAttach and onCreate methods in TestDialogFragment and they don't get hit, which goes against what I read in the android fragment API Guide. Is there something I'm doing wrong with the add transaction above?

P.S. TestDialogFragment extends Fragment

Comment: Does your TestDialogFragment extend the support library fragment base class? If so, you should be calling getSupportFragmentManager

Comment: `gettFragmentManager()` with two `t` ?

Comment: @Kuffs It just extends the regular Fragment class, I'm not using support libraries, I've added some clarification in the OP.

Comment: @Little Child, that was just a typo on stack overflow - thanks for point it out

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by setting & getting arguments with Bundles instead of interacting directly with the fragment via its public methods after committing the transaction. My mistake was assuming that the fragment was up and ready to use (attached, layout inflated etc) as soon as the commit() statement was finished.